# Autowired bean are not handled in my Controller bean (Spring-MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, autowired

I create a Controller bean to map a dedicated URI.

**web.xml** file :

```
    <!-- Spring MVC Servlet (that will route HTTP requests to BlazeDS) -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-main-config.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <!-- We are only using BlazeDS AMF channels to communicate with FlexClient, so let's map URLs accordingly. -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>        
 </servlet-mapping>   

        <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-filter-config.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
               <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
               </listener-class>
        </listener>
```

**spring-main-config.xml** file :

```
 <!-- Import configuration base -->
 <import resource="spring-base-config.xml"/>  

 <!-- Flex integration within Spring. -->
 <flex:message-broker services-config-path="/WEB-INF/flex-services-config.xml">
  <flex:remoting-service />
 </flex:message-broker>

 <!-- Session-scoped bean for User Info -->
 <bean class="com.sharehunter.businessservices.common.UserSessionInfo" scope="session">
  <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
 </bean>
```

**spring-filter-config.xml** file :

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
   <value>
   /fbauth=myController
   </value>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="myController" 
  class="myapp.controller.myController" />
```

My bean controller file :

```
package myapp.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

    public class MyController extends AbstractController{

    @Autowired
    UserSesson userSession;

    @Autowired
    BusinessLogger logger;

 @Override
 protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

  // TO DO - Facebook authentication
  return null;
 }
 }
```

My problem : all my Autowired bean in my Controller bean is already at equal at null. I don't understand where is the issue in my configuration ...

Thank you very much for your help !

Anthony

Answer (score 2):

You have two different contextx defined (`spring-filter-config.xml` and `spring-main-config.xml`), but you should probably only have one. `<context:annotation-driven/>` is only defined in `spring-main-config.xml`, and not in `spring-filter-config.xml`, so any beans defined in `spring-filter-config.xml` won't be autowired.

You have your controllers defined in `spring-filter-config.xml`, but controllers are supposed to be associated with the `ServiceDispatcherServlet`.  You need to move the contents of `spring-filter-config.xml` into `spring-main-config.xml`, and then remove the `ContextLoaderListener` - you don't seem to have any proper use for it.

Comment: Hi Skaffman, in fact <context:annotation-config /> is present in my spring-base-config.xml (import since spring-main-config.xml). So, this annotation should be too in my spring-filter-config.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

where is your bean mapping ??

mention in the xml file there then @Autowired identify by default that which bean class is to be called...